# How can I trace the source of ConfigurationManager.AppSettings?

Tags: c#, configuration

I have the following code on my AppModel base class:

```
        public string GetParameter(string key)
        {
            //Allow local config file to override DB setting
            string retval = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(retval))
            {
                Trace.TraceInformation("{0} from ConfigurationManager.AppSettings is '{1}'", key, retval);
                return retval;
            }

            //No setting in config file - check for ProfileParameter from DB
            Parameters.TryGetValue(key, out retval);
            Trace.TraceInformation("{0} from ProfileParameter is '{1}'", key, retval);
            return retval;          
        }
```

I see a parameter value in my Excel Addin is coming from ConfigurationManager.AppSettings but I have no idea where it is finding the parameter - what is the path to the config file that ConfigurationManager is using ? Is there a way to ask ConfigurationManager for the source of its knowledge ?

Comment: `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` refers to the `app.config` which should be present in the root folder of your project (ie, where all the other *.cs files are present)

Comment: When an application is compiled, the app.config becomes <executablename>.config but I am building an Addin for Excel - should it be EXCEL.exe.config ?

Comment: To repeat "Is there a way to ask ConfigurationManager for the source of its knowledge ?"

Answer (score 0):

When a config object value is created in VS (Settings > Add new item), it is assigned a default value (which is equal to the value on creation).
When the config file is not found/not load/etc, **that** default is used.

Have a look in your *Settings.Designer.cs* file of your project for the attribute `global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute` above your setting.

Example of the settings in a Testing project:

```
[global::System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("This is my default string value")] // << This is what you are looking for
public string TestSetting
{
  get
  {
    return ((string)(this["TestSetting"]));
  }
}

[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("False")]  // << This is what you are looking for
public bool AnotherSetting
{
  get
  {
    return ((bool)(this["AnotherSetting"]));
  }
  set
  {
    this["AnotherSetting"] = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: There are 2 ways to do configuration out of the box that I am aware of: 'Settings' which you describe are accessed through Properties.Settings.Default which I am not currently using (tracking down the actual config file and having to call Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade() gives me a headache !); the alternative is creating an App.Config with <configuration><appSettings> elements which is turned into <executablename>.config when the application is compiled and accessed via ConfigurationManager.AppSettings and is (as far as I know) not subject to the roaming complications